# Сan a creature that is immune to fear be under the effects of Madness?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, immunities, fear, sanity

Сan a creature that is immune to fear be under the effects of Madness?

For example, can a creature under a Heroism spell be under the effect of Madness?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes. Frightened and Madness are different effects with different rules.

Frightened and Madness are different effects with different rules. Immunity to one does not confer immunity to the other, because the rules don’t say anything about that. They each have their own rules, and apart from a specific effect using both together, there is no interaction between the two.